Title bar App name not changing to the application name
I'm trying to change the app name in the title bar.
The name is correct here:

But here it is incorrect on the Titlebar.

I changed the application name in Edit Application Definition.

Thanks for any help.

That section in the title bar is called the "Logo" and can be set here:
Shared Components > User Interface Attributes > Logo

What is shown in the browser tab ("Test_Questionnaire 123" in your case) is the title (not name) attribute of the current page.
